# How to Calculate specific cell total in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, azure-sql-reporting

As shown below image i have problem to calculated specific fields total.

I want to just calculate only two cells value like 
**total=(total opening-qty) + (total purchase-qty)** cell and opening, purchase, sales are all from Type Group.

Please tell me the Expression or tips.

[image]

Comment: what formula do use to compute Total Opening & Total Purchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing your DataSet/report, but the expression would be similar to:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!Type.Value = "OPENING" or Fields!Type.Value = "PURCHASE"
  , Fields!qty.Value
  , Nothing)
```

This will take a `SUM` of all **qty** values, but it will ignore any **Type** rows that don't match the types you're specifying, i.e. *OPENING* and *PURCHASE*.

The most import thing is to make sure the expression is in the correct Scope, i.e. if you're grouping by **Type** the expression should be applied outside of that group Scope to make sure the expression is considering all the required rows.